# c# add data to firebird database

Tags: c#, database, firebird

There is code that I use to pass new data to Database (firebird):

```
FbConnection fbCon = new FbConnection(csb.ToString());
FbDataAdapter fbDAdapter = new FbDataAdapter("SELECT ID,name,score FROM players",fbCon);
FbCommandBuilder Cmd = new FbCommandBuilder(fbDAdapter);
DataSet DSet = new DataSet();
fbDAdapter.Fill(DSet);
DataRow rw = DSet.Tables[0].NewRow();
rw["ID"] = zID + 1;
rw["name"] = var;
rw["score"] = score;
DSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add(rw);
fbDAdapter.Update(DSet);
```

Maybe you can suggest better algorithm, or this is pretty good?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way is OK, you are using a command builder that do a lot of work for, you can simply translate the above code into an insert command to execute directly on the database table :

```
  FbConnection fbCon = new FbConnection(csb.ToString());
  FbCommand fbCom = new FbCommand("INSERT INTO players(ID,name,score) VALUES (@id,@name,@score)", fbCon);
  fbCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", zID + 1);
  fbCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", var);
  fbCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("score", score);
  fbCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

In this way you avoid the command builder and loading the data into the Datatable, should be quite faster ...

Comment: ok, addisional question, witch method is better to use if I want to check if data already exist in DB?
in my example I know how to make that.
How to make checking of existance in your ?

Answer (score 0):

This is lighter for database:

```
      FbConnectionStringBuilder csb = new FbConnectionStringBuilder( );
      csb.ServerType = FbServerType.Default;
      csb.Database = Settings.Default.LastBDPath;
      csb.Password = Settings.Default.LastBDPassword; //            "masterkey";
      csb.UserID = Settings.Default.LastBDUser;       //            "SYSDBA";
      connection = new FbConnection( csb.ToString( ) );

      connection.Open( ); 

      string scriptLine = string.Format("INSERT INTO TABLE (Id, Name, Score) values ({0}, '{1}', {2}", zId+1, var, score) ; 
      FBCommand command = new FbCommand( scriptline, connection );
      command.ExecuteNonQuery( );
```

For a select:

```
string sql = string.Format("select * from table where name='{0}';", your_name);

FbCommand command = new FbCommand( sql ), connection );
FbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader( );
while ( reader.Read( ) )
{
    for ( int i=0; i<reader.FieldCount; i++ )
    {
         objects[i].Add( reader.GetValue( i ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: oh, thnx, is there any method to check if value exist in DB, for example name?

Comment: of course, you should use a sql select, if reader return rows it exists