# Firebird unknown token where

Tags: c#, sql, firebird

I am executing `UPDATE` OR `INSERT` command with `WHERE` statement and I've got this error:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
     FbConnection con = new FbConnection(@"User = SYSDBA; Password = masterkey; Database = D:\TDWORK.fdb; DataSource = localhost; Port = 3050; Dialect = 3; Charset = NONE; Role = admin; Connection lifetime = 15; Pooling = true; MinPoolSize = 0; MaxPoolSize = 50; Packet Size = 8192; ServerType = 0; ");
     FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("UPDATE OR INSERT INTO ZAPOSLENI (ULOGA) VALUES (" + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString() + ") WHERE ZAPID = " + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value + " ", con);
     con.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     con.Close();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
  }
}
```

And here is how command looks like when debugger insert values in it:

```
UPDATE OR INSERT INTO ZAPOSLENI (ULOGA) VALUES (1) WHERE ZAPID = 0
```

Comment: Your current code is unsafe as it is open to SQL injection. You should really use parameters.

Comment: You are concatenating values into the query string, which is unsafe. You need to use parameters, see for an example [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10438372/466862)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `WHERE` in an insert or update clause (see [`UPDATE OR INSERT`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-update-or-insert.html)). If you want to insert a row, when there is no record with `ZAPID = 0` use the following statement:

```
UPDATE OR INSERT INTO ZAPOSLENI (ZAPID, ULOGA) VALUES (0, 1) MATCHING (ZAPID)
```

EDIT: Complete example

```cs
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        FbConnection con = new FbConnection(@"User = SYSDBA; Password = masterkey; Database = D:\TDWORK.fdb; DataSource = localhost; Port = 3050; Dialect = 3; Charset = NONE; Role = admin; Connection lifetime = 15; Pooling = true; MinPoolSize = 0; MaxPoolSize = 50; Packet Size = 8192; ServerType = 0; ");
        FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("UPDATE OR INSERT INTO ZAPOSLENI (ZAPID, ULOGA) VALUES (" + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString() + ", " + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value + ") MATCHING (ZAPID)", con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not working. It says that Update or insert doesn't match MATCHING clause. Here is command:

`FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("UPDATE OR INSERT INTO ZAPOSLENI (ULOGA) VALUES (" + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString() + ") MATCHING (ZAPID) ", con);`

Comment: I think you have to include the `ZAPID`in the columns and the values, like I did in the answer.

Comment: Did the answer helped you?